# IF YES then copy another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have been using Google Sheets and getting things done slowly. I am using an extension called Autocrat and have been doing ok with it. (Not sure if there is a better alternative.)

My current problem is this.

I have various sheets designed to how I want them and that works ok. I work in car sales, so there are quite a few cells used.
When I sell a car, I enter the buyer's name and details. If they have a part exchange, I then add their details (Again).

I have a column with a YES/NO dropdown for if they have a part exchange or not.

What I would like to do is this....If I click YES to having a part exchange, it then copies the buyer's details over to the sellers section for the part exchange.

Simply put, IF one cell says YES, the the cell I am in, take the info from the other cell. If it says no, then it is left blank.

The exact thing I need is this. IF Y23=YES, then copy E23 to Z23....So, this is what I entered into the empty cell where I would like the details from E23:

```
=IF(Y23="YES", "E23","")
```

I am in Spain. The reference cells are just NAME, ADDRESS, TEL No, EMAIL. I enter them in the first cells and if it is YES to a part exchange, I would like them copied to the Part Exchange section. The ERROR message is just **FORMULA PARSE ERROR** and from the research I have done, it seems it could be a multitude of things.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148045/discussion-on-question-by-steve-if-yes-then-copy-another-cell); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Steve: The above comment is a "canned comment" added automatically when a moderator moves comments into a chatroom. You have been granted explicit writing access, which allows you to use the chatroom even if you don't yet have the required reputation to use the chat platform. Please continue the conversation about this question in the chatroom linked in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your spreadsheet's local setting is likely Spain as you are in Spain. This locale uses the semicolon `;` character as a function parameter separator instead of the comma `,` character. This is consistent with the FORMULA PARSE ERROR message.

Replace

```
=IF(Y23="YES", "E23","")
```

by

```
=IF(Y23="YES"; "E23";"")
```